# why would assigning to dataframe with loc and and a slice be different than with a single column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to update a column from float to int.  consider `df` in the following two scenarios:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1.1, 2], B=[1., 2]))
print(df.A.dtype)

df.loc[:, ['A']] = df[['A']].astype(int)
print(df.A.dtype)
df
```

[image]

The dtype failed to update to `int` but the value in `'A'` is definitely truncated.

---

However,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1.1, 2], B=[1., 2]))
print(df.A.dtype)

df.loc[:, 'A'] = df.A.astype(int)
print(df.A.dtype)
df
```

[image]

works just fine.

Is there a justification for these behaving differently?

Comment: Interesting find. It seems to work as long as your `loc` selection doesn't involve a `[]` of columns. That is, `df.loc[:, 'A'] =  df[['A']].astype(int)` works like `df.loc[:, 'A'] = df.A.astype(int)`.

Comment: While this does not constitute a robust justification, these differences may have to do with the fact that in the first case, you are changing the data type of a `DataFrame` while in the second case, you are changing the data type of a `Series`.

Comment: If you use "df[['A']] = df[['A']].astype(int)", it will return A with type of int64... I guess it's sth related with loc and [] function in detailed way, maybe also ask in https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues will get better result

Comment: Probably because pandas upgrades the `int` to `float` on assignment from a DataFrame... And that probably happens because `Series` != `DataFrame`.

Comment: I would hazard that it's because `df.loc[:, 'A']` is a `Series` but `df.loc[:, ['A']]` is a `DataFrame` with a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#astype):

> Note When trying to convert a subset of columns to a specified type
> using astype() and loc(), upcasting occurs. loc() tries to fit in what
> we are assigning to the current dtypes, while [] will overwrite them
> taking the dtype from the right hand side. Therefore the following
> piece of code produces the unintended result.